# How to use UV coord based on modulo with a shader?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, tiling

I don't understand how to write the tiling code to repeat an image on a mesh : the material contains the texture, so is it `TEXCOORD0` that should be used instead of the "vertex" information?

---

EDIT: Previous code :

vertex :

```
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

void main() {
    vec2 modXZ = vec2 (mod (a_position.x, u_widthImg),
                       mod (a_position.z, u_heightImg));

    v_texCoord0 = modXZ / vec2 (u_widthImg, u_heightImg);

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

fragment :

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture0;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0; 

void main() {
    vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_texture0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_texCoord0.x *color1, 0, v_texCoord0.y*color1, 1.0);
}
```

It says "too many arguments for constructor vec4". I don't know what this means, maybe it is about `gl_TexCoord[0]`.

---

EDIT NEW CODE :

vertex :

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform float u_widthImg;
uniform float u_heightImg;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    vec2 modXZ = vec2 (mod (a_position.x, u_widthImg),
                       mod (a_position.z, u_heightImg));

    v_texCoord0 = modXZ / vec2 (u_widthImg, u_heightImg);
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

fragment :

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture0;

varying vec2 v_texCoord0; 
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture0, v_texCoord0) * v_color;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First of all, this is ***not*** a GLSL shader.

`float2`, `half4`, `tex2D (...)`, `: SV_POSITION`, etc. are all HLSL / Cg.

#### What is more, the modulus operator is not going to work in GLSL on a floating-point type.

The `%` operator may not even work on an integer type if your GPU does not support [`GL_EXT_gpu_shader4`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_EXT_gpu_shader4.txt). You could use the built-in [`mod (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/mod.xhtml) function, but again your shader is not actually GLSL to begin with.

---

#### UPDATE:

You are currently mismatching the dimensionality of `mod (...)`. It will return a floating-point scalar, but you are trying to store that in a `vec2`.

#### Use this instead:

```
void main() {
    vec2 modXZ = vec2 (mod (a_position.x, u_widthImg),
                       mod (a_position.z, u_heightImg));

    v_texCoord0 = modXZ / vec2 (u_widthImg, u_heightImg);

    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

As for the last error in your question, that comes from your fragment shader, which you have not shown. I know this because the line number is out-of-synch with the others and the only `z` swizzle in your shader is for `a_position`, which is declared as `vec3`.

Comment: Thanks, I mixed it up a little bit, because I wanted to test the code in `Unity`, and then change it to be readable with `Libgdx` (which uses `Glsl`). I edited my code, but I have multiple errors, would you know how to solve them? It looks like in theory, I have to do the modulo on the vertex, and pass the new texture coordinates in a varying to be used in the fragment shader.

Comment: Correct, thank you! I use "y" in the fragment file instead of "z", and it works. I edited my post, could you have a look? I don't see why the texture is then not applied? It is a gradient between red and blue.

Comment: You don't have a `sampler2D` uniform in your shader or a `texture2D (...)` that uses it. You need to add those things to your fragment shader otherwise you're just going to output your texture coordinates in the form of a color. Textures are usually bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` by default, so you can assign the new `sampler2D` uniform a value of **0** (probably defaults to this, but you should know why you want the number **0** - it means `GL_TEXTURE<n>`).

Comment: Thanks, I have many questions but it is maybe specific to libgdx... I edited my post above, just in case

Comment: @Paul: The problem is that you are trying to multiply `v_texCoord0.x * color1` and store the result as a scalar. Scalar * Vector multiplication is defined, but the result is a vector (it is component-wise multiplication). You could replace that with `v_texCoord0.x * color1.x`, but honestly I don't know why you are multiplying by the texture coordinates in the first place - they are only needed when you do the texture lookup. You can write `gl_FragColor = color1` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all your answers. I don't know how to make this work. I found a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mIdNru2VO0), the guy seems to call `a_color` in the vertex file, then pass it to the fragment file and multiply `texture2D` with it, but in my case, I still get a black screen, as if nothing was rendered. Would you know why? I edited the post above with the previous code and the new one. (Edit: and I did not send the texture directly to the shader, I only added the texture to the material, that is rendered with the shader)